# Tkinter not saving entry as variable

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I've tried looking at other peoples code snippets online, tried looking at previous solutions and NOTHING WORKS. I need to save the fee entry as a variable when the button is clicked.

Here's all the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from bitcoin import *
with open ("wallet.dat", "r") as file:
    priv=file.read()
my_addr = privtoaddr(priv)

url = 'https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1DswsKETdbXkrw5Br1Tbvu6hCbpQ7QCRc7'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
balance = soup.body.find(class_="sc-1ryi78w-0 cILyoi sc-16b9dsl-1 ZwupP u3ufsr-0 eQTRKC")
print(balance)

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        #setting title
        root.title("BeanWallet | Send")
        #setting window size
        width=354
        height=246
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        root.geometry(alignstr)
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        GLabel_764=tk.Label(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=16)
        GLabel_764["font"] = ft
        GLabel_764["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_764["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_764["text"] = "BeanWallet"
        GLabel_764.place(x=0,y=0,width=105,height=41)

        GButton_815=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_815["bg"] = "#efefef"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GButton_815["font"] = ft
        GButton_815["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_815["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_815["text"] = "Home"
        GButton_815.place(x=110,y=10,width=55,height=23)
        GButton_815["command"] = self.GButton_815_command

        GButton_888=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_888["bg"] = "#efefef"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GButton_888["font"] = ft
        GButton_888["fg"] = "#6a6969"
        GButton_888["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_888["text"] = "Send"
        GButton_888.place(x=170,y=10,width=55,height=23)
        GButton_888["command"] = self.GButton_888_command

        GButton_30=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_30["bg"] = "#efefef"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GButton_30["font"] = ft
        GButton_30["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_30["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_30["text"] = "Receive"
        GButton_30.place(x=230,y=10,width=55,height=23)
        GButton_30["command"] = self.GButton_30_command

        GButton_458=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_458["bg"] = "#efefef"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GButton_458["font"] = ft
        GButton_458["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_458["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_458["text"] = "Settings"
        GButton_458.place(x=290,y=10,width=55,height=23)
        GButton_458["command"] = self.GButton_458_command

        GLabel_84=tk.Label(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLabel_84["font"] = ft
        GLabel_84["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_84["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_84["text"] = "Send To:"
        GLabel_84.place(x=0,y=40,width=352,height=25)

        GLineEdit_642=tk.Entry(root)
        GLineEdit_642["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLineEdit_642["font"] = ft
        GLineEdit_642["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLineEdit_642["justify"] = "center"
        GLineEdit_642["text"] = "Address"
        GLineEdit_642.place(x=0,y=60,width=352,height=30)

        GLabel_227=tk.Label(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLabel_227["font"] = ft
        GLabel_227["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_227["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_227["text"] = "Amount:"
        GLabel_227.place(x=0,y=90,width=353,height=25)

        GLineEdit_37=tk.Entry(root)
        GLineEdit_37["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLineEdit_37["font"] = ft
        GLineEdit_37["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLineEdit_37["justify"] = "center"
        GLineEdit_37["text"] = "0.0001"
        GLineEdit_37.place(x=0,y=110,width=352,height=30)

        GLabel_669=tk.Label(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLabel_669["font"] = ft
        GLabel_669["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_669["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_669["text"] = "Fee (sat/vB)"
        GLabel_669.place(x=0,y=140,width=102,height=30)

        fee = tk.IntVar()
        GLineEdit_932=tk.Entry(root, textvariable=fee)
        GLineEdit_932.focus()
        GLineEdit_932.pack()
        GLineEdit_932["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLineEdit_932["font"] = ft
        GLineEdit_932["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLineEdit_932["justify"] = "center"
        GLineEdit_932["text"] = "Fee"
        GLineEdit_932.place(x=0,y=170,width=101,height=30)

        GButton_254=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_254["bg"] = "#efefef"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GButton_254["font"] = ft
        GButton_254["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_254["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_254["text"] = "Send"
        GButton_254.place(x=250,y=150,width=90,height=50)
        GButton_254["command"] = self.GButton_254_command

        GLabel_60=tk.Label(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLabel_60["font"] = ft
        GLabel_60["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_60["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_60["text"] = "Balance displayed in console."
        GLabel_60.place(x=0,y=210,width=353,height=30)

    def GButton_815_command(self):
        root.destroy()
        mypath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        os.system( f'"{mypath}/home.py"' )


    def GButton_888_command(self):
        print("command")


    def GButton_30_command(self):
        root.destroy()
        mypath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        os.system( f'"{mypath}/receive.py"' )


    def GButton_458_command(self):
        root.destroy()
        mypath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        os.system( f'"{mypath}/settings.py"' )

    def GButton_254_command(self):
        fees = self.fee.get()
        print(fees)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I get this error code no matter how much I change the code up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ThaSq\Downloads\BTCWEB\BeanWallet\remastered\send.py", line 172, in GButton_254_command
    fees = self.fee.get()
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'fee'
```

I've tried using GLineEdit_932.get() and that doesn't work either. I've also tried making the variable a global variable, with no success.

Comment: `fee` is created after the line `print(fees)`, so how can you access it before it is created?

Comment: @acw1668 I've tried putting the print(fees) in a button function that was called after the entry was entered and it didn't work.

Comment: `fee` is a local variable inside `__init__()` function in the updated code, so it cannot be accessed elsewhere.  Learn about [python-scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Comment: Note also that `GLineEdit_932["text"] = "Fee"` will not insert "Fee" into the `Entry` widget.  It just change the `textvariable` option instead.

Comment: @acw1668, that wasn't my biggest concern but I'd love to know how to enter text into the entry widget, could you help?

Comment: That is the cause why you get 0 from `fee.get()`.  To insert text into `Entry` widget, use `GLineEdit_932.insert('end', 'Fee')`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you do, because you are trying to USE the variable before you have CREATED it.  But in this case, moving those lines isn't the right answer.  You need that fetching code to be in a separate function.  SO, for example:

```
def create_ui():
    def get_input():
        fees = fee.get()
        print(fees)

    fee = tk.IntVar()
    GLineEdit_932=tk.Entry(root, textvariable=fee)
    GLineEdit_932.focus()
    ...
```

Now you can call `create_ui()` to do the one-time initialization, but your button callback can call the little `get_input` function to fetch the values.

### Followup

Having seen your full code, there is a better way.

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        #setting title
        ...
        self.fee = tk.IntVar()
        GLineEdit_932=tk.Entry(root, textvariable=self.fee)
        GLineEdit_932.focus()
        ...
        GButton_254.place(x=250,y=150,width=90,height=50)
        GButton_254["command"] = self.get_input
        ...
        GLabel_60["text"] = "Balance displayed in console."
        GLabel_60.place(x=0,y=210,width=353,height=30)

    def get_input(self):
        fees = self.fee.get()
        print(fees)
```

You can see that your sample is doing this kind of thing for the other buttons.  Follow the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for. I should've posted the whole code so there could be a better understanding of what I'm trying to achieve. BUT I'm not sure where I would call the create_ui() function as the button that prints the variables out in console is the only button that is calling a function. I would like for the GUI to open up, have someone enter the fee and press submit and have it return the text that was entered by the user. BTW I'm very new to Python so still trying to grasp a lot of information.

Comment: Well, if your current code works at all, then you must be calling `get_input` at a global level somewhere.  Otherwise, the lineedit and button would not be created at all.  Just change that to `create_ui`.  If NOTHING works, then maybe you aren't calling it.  You need to set up the UI and call `root.mainloop()` before anything will display.

Comment: The code does work but I'm not calling get_input at a global level, I posted the whole code if that helps any.

Comment: That code is substantially different than what you originally posted.  The solution here is just to move the whole `get_input()` function inside of `App.__init__`, so it has access to the `fee` variable.  Or, store it in `self.fee`, and make `get_input` another class method.

Comment: I tried using your followup code and it finally will print something without an error, but now it just prints 0 no matter what number I enter. (Just changed fee to self.fee)

Comment: @Bean As I said in my last comment to your question, you need to remove the line `GLineEdit_932["text"] = "Fee"`.

Comment: @acw1668 didn't know that would fix it totally, but it did! Thank both of you so much!